# ¿Como encuentro una palabra dentro de un archivo .txt?

Tags: java, string, archivo, netbeans-11

estoy haciendo un proyecto que consiste en buscar un código dentro de un archivo .txt y si el código se encuentra en el archivo, imprime la linea en la que se encuentra el código. 
Por ejemplo tengo mi código que es "180103" y en mi fichero tengo algo así:

180103 A18 Lunes Biologia

260202 A Martes Ingles

260103 A Lunes Lógica

260203 A Martes Español

260104 A Lunes Química

Deberia sair asi

```
180103 A18 Lunes Biologia
```

Pero no sale nada, el problema que tengo es que no encuentra el codigo que busco.

Ayuda por favor!!!!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Prueba{

public static void main(String [] args){
    String codigo = "180103"; 

    boolean x = false;
    int j = 0;

    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{ 
    archivo =  new File ("HorariosTexto.txt");
    fr = new FileReader (archivo);
    br = new BufferedReader (fr);  

    String Linea;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conectado");

    while((Linea = br.readLine()) !=null){
        if(Linea.indexOf(codigo) != -1){   
            String[] campos = Linea.split(" ");
            while(j < campos.length){  
               System.out.println(" "+campos[j]); 
                j++;
            }
        }
    }   
} catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de conexion.");
    }finally{
        try{
            if(null != fr){
                fr.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e2){
         }
        }
       }
      }
```

Comment: Que mensaje de error tienes? A mi si me sale.

Comment: no me sale ningun error, solo no imprime la linea

Comment: Si, el programa al ejecutar if(Linea.indexOf(codigo) != -1) no encuentra que en Linea exista el String que indica tu variable codigo entonces no imprime nada. Has verificado que realmente tu archivo de texto contenga la cadena de caracteres "180103"?

Comment: PD: Has probado con otros códigos de tu fichero de texto?

Comment: Si, he probado con los otros codigos pero en ninguno lo enuentra. Tambien probe con contains pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Estás utilizando el fichero que contiene el texto? A veces, indicamos una ruta de un fichero que pensamos que contiene el texto pero que realmente está vacio. Te recomiendo que antes imprimas el contenido del fichero de texto.

Comment: Ya revisé la ruta y lo imprimi, si es la correcta